# Find a kernel module behind virtual network interface by info from sysfs/procfs

Tags: linux-kernel, network-interface, kernel-modules, proc, sysfs

I'd like to find kernel module which is behind virtual network interface (e.g interfaces using `veth`, `dummy` kernel modules, *NOT* physical NIC). It's easy with `ethtool`:

```
$ ethtool -i ltp_ns_veth2 |grep driver
driver: veth
```

But I don't want to depend on it. I know I can find module for physical NIC:

```
$ basename $(readlink -f /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/module)
e1000
```

But this doesn't work for virtual devices as there is no link to `device` folder.

Best would be to be able to obtain the info with parsing `/sys`, because it does not require external tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dmesg | grep eth` if you know the interface name would contain eth.

```
[root@psybox ~]# dmesg | grep -i eth
[    2.009028] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
```

The driver is displayed second, **vmxnet3**.

Comment: No, that's not correct for my case. `dmesg` tells you info about physical NIC (in that case is better to use info from sysfs, as I wrote in question). But dmesg does NOT tell you info about virtual NIC (NIC which use `veth` od `dummy` kernel module).

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is utility `ethtool`. It show exact the kernel module name:

```
ethtool -i $IFACE | grep driver
```

`iproute2` can show device type. It is not a driver name, but they are often the same:

```
 ip -detail -json link list dev $IFACE | jq '.[] | .linkinfo.info_kind'
```

In some cases, the `lshw` and `systool` utilities will help to collect information:

```
systool -c net -v | less
lshw | less
```

Comment: Well, I asked for something else than `ethtool`. `ip` example does work for `veth`, but not for `e1000e` => not universal. Thanks for `systool` (I'd prefer parsing `/sys` because it does not require external tools, but `systool` is interesting, although `ethtool` is probably more common).